# Matplotlib integrated in a QScrollArea isn't refresh curves properly on mac OS

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, qscrollbar

I have an issue with a matplotlib figure that I've embedded in a pyqt5 `QScrollArea`.
My issue is when I'm scrolling down, it is like only the top of the matplotlib has been updated.
For instance, in the image below, the curves below the curve number 35 are not updated properly.

This only happens with mac OS but it run well on Windows 10.
I don't find the issue in the code.

### Update

To me, it looks like the matplotlib figure doesn't match with the QSrollBar. I try to explain more. When I scroll down with the Qsrollbar, the Matplotlib figure is going down but not as fast as the scrollbar. I see that with the number of curve that is increasing when I scroll down. It is like the Qscrollbar go down too fast with respect to the matplotlib figure update.

[image]

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import numpy as np
import time

class Viewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        #######################################
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainVBOX_param_scene = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mascene = plot(self)


        self.paramPlotV = QVBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalSliders  = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSliders.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.horizontalSliders.valueChanged.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.horizontalSliders.setMinimum(0)
        self.horizontalSliders.setMaximum(1)


        self.paramPlot = QHBoxLayout()
        l_gain = QLabel('Gain')
        self.e_gain = QLineEdit('5')
        l_win = QLabel('Window')
        self.e_win = QLineEdit('10')
        l_spacing = QLabel('vertical spacing')
        self.e_spacing = QLineEdit('10')
        l_linewidth = QLabel('linewidth')
        self.e_linewidth = QLineEdit('1')

        self.e_gain.returnPressed.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.e_win.returnPressed.connect(self.udpate_plot_plus_slider)
        self.e_spacing.returnPressed.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.e_linewidth.returnPressed.connect(self.update_plot)

        self.paramPlot.addWidget(l_gain)
        self.paramPlot.addWidget(self.e_gain)
        self.paramPlot.addWidget(l_win)
        self.paramPlot.addWidget(self.e_win)
        self.paramPlot.addWidget(l_spacing)
        self.paramPlot.addWidget(self.e_spacing)
        self.paramPlot.addWidget(l_linewidth)
        self.paramPlot.addWidget(self.e_linewidth)

        self.paramPlotV.addWidget(self.horizontalSliders)
        self.paramPlotV.addLayout(self.paramPlot)

        self.mainVBOX_param_scene.addWidget(self.mascene)
        self.mainVBOX_param_scene.addLayout(self.paramPlotV)

        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainVBOX_param_scene)

        self.Fs = 1024
        self.Sigs_dict = np.random.rand(50,20*self.Fs)
        self.t = np.arange(self.Sigs_dict.shape[1])/self.Fs
        self.parent.processEvents()
        self.update()

    def updateslider(self):
        self.horizontalSliders.setMinimum(0)
        self.horizontalSliders.setMaximum(np.ceil(self.t[-1]/int(self.e_win.text()))-1)
        self.horizontalSliders.setPageStep(1)
        self.horizontalSliders.update()

    def udpate_plot_plus_slider(self):
        self.updateslider()
        self.mascene.update()

    def update_plot(self):
        t0 = time.time()
        self.mascene.update()
        print('time old:', time.time()-t0)

    def update(self):
        self.updateslider()
        self.mascene.modify_sigs()
        self.mascene.update()

class plot(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(plot, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.figure = plt.figure(facecolor='white')#Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.widget.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.widget.layout().setSpacing(0)
        self.scroll = QScrollArea(self.widget)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.canvas)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def modify_sigs(self):
        self.Sigs_dict = self.parent.Sigs_dict
        self.t = self.parent.t
        self.Fs= self.parent.Fs


    def update(self):
        win_num = self.parent.horizontalSliders.value()
        self.figure.clear()
        plt.figure(self.figure.number)
        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.01, right=1, top=1, wspace=0.0 , hspace=0.0 )
        self.axes = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
        gain = float(self.parent.e_gain.text())
        win= float(self.parent.e_win.text())
        self.spacing = float(self.parent.e_spacing.text())
        linewidth = float(self.parent.e_linewidth.text())
        ts = int(win*(win_num) * self.Fs)
        te = ts + int(win * self.Fs)
        if te > len(self.t):
            te=len(self.t)
        for i in range(self.Sigs_dict.shape[0]):
            line, = plt.plot(self.t[ts:te], gain*(self.Sigs_dict[i,ts:te]-np.mean(self.Sigs_dict[i,ts:te]))+i*self.spacing, linewidth=linewidth  )


        self.axes.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=True)
        self.axes.set_ylim((-self.spacing,(self.Sigs_dict.shape[0]+1)*self.spacing))
        self.axes.set_xlim((ts/ self.Fs, ts / self.Fs + win ))

        self.axes.set_yticks(np.arange(self.Sigs_dict.shape[0]) * self.spacing)
        self.axes.set_yticklabels([str(n) for n in np.arange(self.Sigs_dict.shape[0])])



        self.canvas.setGeometry(0, 0, self.parent.width()-100, (self.parent.height()-100)*self.spacing)
        self.canvas.draw()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    ex = Viewer(app)
    ex.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update the version of my matplotlib module from 3.1.1 to 3.2.0rc1 and it solves the issue.